# Cursing a Jews' possessions/property/assets

Tags: curse

There is a prohibition of a Jew cursing another Jew (see [Vayikra 19:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.19.14?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he), Rashi).

Does this extend to a Jew cursing the possessions/property/assets of a Jew as well?

For example, if there is an evil Jew, can you curse that Jews' business i.e., for it to fail? If there is a Jew who repeatedly drives dangerously (i.e., life threateningly) can you curse that Jew's car i.e., that it will be damaged (without injuring the person) to the extent that he wont be able to drive it recklessly (and get the point)? For example: you see a reckless driver at a traffic light and you say (I am not sure of the 'proper' formulation of a curse, but something to the effect of:) "I curse your car (not you), that if you keep driving recklessly, the car will be permanently damaged". For example an act of God destroyed the car when the person wasn't in the car.

Comment: Isn't such a curse by extension leaving room for a scenario where it becomes "permanently damaged" through an accident and thereby potentially injuring the individual?

Comment: @Dov that was implied. I edited the question slightly if that helps.